# Creating a category and subcategory system to news management

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Im creating a news website, and in the news website will have a category and subcategory management, i already created the tables and also can manage categories and subcategories, the only issue is regarding how i will associante the posts with the categories in my create post, should i create in my table "posts" create 2 columns, the "category_id" and the "subcategory_id" ? It doesnt look quite correct, since only by giving one of them i should already no wich one is catgory and subcategory, and i would no if my categories and subcategories column were only one, but in my case it isnt. I feel how i created my tables for posts, categories and subcategories is not quite how sould it be, here i leave my code:

```
Posts:´
-id;
- title;
- body;

Categories:
- id;
- name;

Category_Subcategory:
- id;
- name;
- category_id;
```

So how should i associante the category or subcategory to posts? Is this the correct way im doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you could use a self-parenting relation for the categories. This can allow you to create a n-level of categories (you can limit that on your source code)

```
Categories:
 - id
 - name
 - parent_id (FK to Categories.id, Null if is a root category)

Posts:
 - id
 - title
 - content
 - category_id
```

So, example:

```
Category [#1, 'Financial', NULL] = Root category Financial
Category [#2, 'Crisis', 1] = Sub-category linked to Financial one
```

You have another solution: many-to-many-polymorphic-relations
You can create a relation post to category and another post to subcategory

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 1):

You can assign foreign key of sub_category_id in Posts table.
table schema like

Posts:
-id;
- title;
- body;
- sub_category_id

Categories:
- id;
- name;

Category_Subcategory:
- id;
- name;
- category_id;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this structure if post will have just one Category and one Sub Category. You need to add `sub_category_id` key to the `posts` table.

Category will have many Sub Categories- it's [`hasMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation
Sub Category will have many Posts - it's [`hasMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) too

If you want to fetch all posts of a Category, you can add [`HasManyThrough()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation between Category and Posts.